# How to create robust access logs using Apache Tomcat Valve Component?

Tags: http, tomcat, http-headers

We are working with Apache Tomcat 7 and trying to setup the Valve Component to store our access logs, ready for processing in [SnowPlow](https://github.com/snowplow/snowplow).

The problem we have is how to make these logs robust. To give an example - we can separate fields with tabs and extract the user agent string like so:

```
pattern="%{yyyy-MM-dd}t&#9;%{hh:mm:ss}t&#9;%{User-Agent}i&#9;"
```

The problem is that the Valve Component does not (as far as I can see) escape `%{User-Agent}i`, so a stray tab in a useragent will corrupt the data (row will look like it contains four fields, not three).

As far as solutions, unless there's a way of escaping the useragent which I've missed, I can see a couple of solutions:

1. Use a really obscure field delimiter (or combination of field delimiters) which is very unlikely to crop up in a useragent string. We tried Ctrl-A (HTML `&#1;`?) but that didn't seem to work
2. Write a custom `AccessLogValve` which either supports escaping or sanitizes tabs - perhaps similar to this post [Sanitizing Tomcat access log entries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5812238/sanitizing-tomcat-access-log-entries)

A bit puzzled that I can't find anything else about this online - does nobody parse their Tomcat access logs?

What do you recommend? We're a little stuck...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I wrote a [custom Tomcat AccessLogValve](https://github.com/snowplow/tomcat-cf-access-log-valve) which:

- Introduced a new pattern, 'I', to escape an incoming header
- Introduced a new pattern, 'C', to fetch a cookie stored on the response
- Re-implemented the pattern 'i' to ensure that "" (empty string) is replaced with "-"
- Re-implemented the pattern 'q' to remove the "?" and ensure "" (empty string) is replaced with "-"
- Overwrote the 'v' pattern, to write the version of this AccessLogValve, rather than the local server name

It seems to be pretty robust - I haven't had any further issues with unescaped values.

Answer (score 1):

[RFC2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-14.43) defines user agent string as

```
User-Agent     = "User-Agent" ":" 1*( product | comment )
```

Then product is defined as

```
product         = token ["/" product-version]
product-version = token
```

Following this, tokens are defined as

```
token          = 1*<any CHAR except CTLs or separators>
```

and separators/CTLs as

```
separators     = "(" | ")" | "<" | ">" | "@"
                      | "," | ";" | ":" | "\" | <">
                      | "/" | "[" | "]" | "?" | "="
                      | "{" | "}" | SP | HT
CTL            = <any US-ASCII control character
                    (octets 0 - 31) and DEL (127)>
```

We need not to forget `comment`, which is defined as

```
comment    = "(" *( ctext | quoted-pair | comment ) ")" 
ctext      = <any TEXT excluding "(" and ")">
quoted-pair    = "\" CHAR
CHAR           = <any US-ASCII character (octets 0 - 127)>
```

So if I understand correctly, you should be able to use any `separator` or `CTL` as long as you can distinguish `comment`, which is wrapped in `(` and `)`. If `(` appears inside the comment, it should be escaped with `\`.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer @mindas, although I'm not sure that I fully understand it. Are you saying that we should simply hope that all useragents that hit our site are RFC2616 compliant, or are you saying that Tomcat has a mechanism to reject non-RFC2616 compliant headers?

Comment: I would expect major browsers to respect RFC, but who knows? As you have access to vast amounts of logs, it's probably best to write some script to test to see if any rogue UAs managed to sneak in. Another approach would be to serialize the logs to some NoSQL store instead of text file. This way UA would sit in a separate column and prevent any ambiguities when parsing.